# How deal with image paths in java?

Tags: java, image

First, let me clarify that I'm a Java programmer by hobby, English isn't my native language, and this is my first question in StackOverflow, so if I'm doing something wrong, I will be grateful in be advised.

When I need to use some image in my applications, I put the image file in bin folder of my project and use the following code to acces that image:

```
Image img1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/confirm.png")).getImage();
```

Recently, I decided let user choose the image with a JFileChooser. The way that I made is get the image path and copy that image into my bin folder, so this way I can use the above line of code. Here's is how I'm doing that:

```
File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/bin/" + "default.png");
ImageIO.write(defaultImage, "png", outputFile);
```

That way I can get a copy of the file in my project folder (C:\Users\renan\Desktop\Image_Editor\bin\default.png).

Everything works fine when I run the application in Eclise, but the things start to go wrong when I create a Runnable JAR file (.jar). When I runed my .jar file over command prompt (java -jar "Image Editor.jar") I've got the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\renan\Desktop\bin\default.png (The system can not find the path specified).
```

After think about this error, I realised that after create a .jar file I can't stay copying the images into my bin folder because now has just a .jar file, not separated folders like before.

**My question is**: What should I do to deal with images that will be used after the program had compiled?

Should I create a folder in my computer that will storage this application images and load the images from that folder? (like games have Screenshots folder to save their images catched by the user).

If anyone can advise me the right way to do this, I will very thankful.

Comment: There are a few ways you might be able to do this, but because the eduction context of the program can change, relative paths aren't a great choice, in fact what you love tried (using user.dir) is among the better choices, as it's a well known location. The issue, of course, is making sure the files  are copied to it. Another choice is to simply maintain a list (stored in a configuration file) of the absolute paths of the images

Comment: So it's a possible (and good) solution, for exemple: 1-Create e folder in C:\Program Files   2-Put my .jar file in there   3-create a "img" folder and code the program to read the images from that folder?

Comment: So long as the img is in well known place (like the user.home (get those confused)). Some versions of windows won't allow you to write to Program Files, so you need to be careful, and because a programs working directory isn't al say the same as the one it's installed in, you don't want to rely on relative paths

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder outside of the JAR. A JAR file essentially a *.zip file on Windows, therefore you can't change any of the folders in the JAR file after it's been compiled because it's in a compressed format.